# training by batches leads to more over-fitting

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, training-data

I'm training a sequence to sequence  (seq2seq) model and I have different values to train on for the `input_sequence_length`.

For values `10` and `15`, I get acceptable results but when I try to train with `20`, I get *memory errors* so I switched the training to train by batches but the model *over-fit* and the validation loss explodes, and even with the accumulated gradient I get the same behavior, so I'm looking for hints and leads to more accurate ways to do the update.

---

Here is my training function (only with batch section) :

```py
    if batch_size is not None:
        k=len(list(np.arange(0,(X_train_tensor_1.size()[0]//batch_size-1), batch_size )))
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            epoch_loss=0
            for i in list(np.arange(0,(X_train_tensor_1.size()[0]//batch_size-1), batch_size )): # by using equidistant batch till the last one it becomes much faster than using the X.size()[0] directly
                sequence = X_train_tensor[i:i+batch_size,:,:].reshape(-1, sequence_length, input_size).to(device)
                labels = y_train_tensor[i:i+batch_size,:,:].reshape(-1, sequence_length, output_size).to(device)
                # Forward pass
                outputs = model(sequence)
                loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                epoch_loss+=loss.item()
                # Backward and optimize
                loss.backward() 

            optimizer.step()    
            epoch_loss=epoch_loss/k
            model.eval
            validation_loss,_= evaluate(model,X_test_hard_tensor_1,y_test_hard_tensor_1)
            model.train()
            training_loss_log.append(epoch_loss)
            print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Train MSELoss: {}, Validation : {} {}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs,epoch_loss,validation_loss))
```

**EDIT:**
here are the parameters that I'm training with :

```py
batch_size = 1024 
num_epochs = 25000
learning_rate = 10e-04

optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
criterion = nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
```

Comment: what is your batch size?

Comment: if your batch_size is small then its as if you are looking at each word one by one and therefore your model will overfit. Depending on your computer memory, I'd suggest batch_size of 32/64 or a multiple of 2^{i}. Out of curiosity, what is your current batch_size?

Comment: Can you please post the `memory errors` as well? As it can be helpful to *understand and use to reproduce the problem*.

Comment: which optimizer do you use?

Comment: for batch and optimizer i updated the question with the details

Comment: @"Muhammad Usman" : the memory error is like this : `CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.64 GiB (GPU 0; 32.00 GiB total capacity; 16.63 GiB already allocated; 50.29 MiB free; 735.23 MiB cached)`

Comment: As per the error concerned Always Remember: There are multiple options to deal with but the more appropriate solution is that It is because of *mini-batch* of data does not fit on to `GPU memory`. **Just decrease the batch size** (It will definitely work). When I set `batch size = 256` for `cifar10` dataset, I got the same error; Then I set the `batch size = 128`, it is solved. Try to reduce your batch size from `1024` to `512`. See if it works.

Comment: @"Muhammad  Usman" that is not what im asking about (i already did that and led me to overfitting) which is why im positing the question as overfiting matter not as a memory matter.

Comment: So for that reason, I started my comment with this statement: *As per the error concerned Always Remember*. I do acknowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Batch size affects regularization. Training on a single example at a time is quite noisy, which makes it harder to overfit. Training on batches smoothes everything out, which makes it easier to overfit. Translating back to regularization:

- Smaller batches add regularization.
- Larger batches reduce regularization.

I am also curious about your learning rate. Every call to `loss.backward()` will accumulate the gradient. If you have set your learning rate to expect a single example at a time, and not reduced it to account for batch accumulation, then one of two things will happen.

1. The learning rate will be too high for the now-accumulated gradient, training will diverge, and both training and validation errors will explode.
2. The learning rate won't be too high, and nothing will diverge. The model will just train more quickly and effectively. If the model is too large for the data being fit, then training error will go to 0 but validation error will explode due to overfitting.

---

**Update**

Here is a bit more detail regarding the gradient accumulation.

Every call to `loss.backward()` will accumulate gradient, until you reset it with `optimizer.zero_grad()`. It will be acted on when you call `optimizer.step()`, based on whatever it has accumulated.

The way your code is written, you call `loss.backward()` for every pass through the inner loop, then you call `optimizer.step()` in the outer loop before resetting. So the gradient has been accumulated, that is summed, over all examples in the batch and not just one example at a time.

Under most assumptions, that will make the batch-accumulated gradient larger than the gradient for a single example. If the gradients are all aligned, for B batches, it will be larger by B times. If the gradients are [i.i.d.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) then it will be more like `sqrt(B)` times larger.

If you do not account for this, then you have effectively increased your learning rate by that factor. Some of that will be mitigated by the smoothing effect of larger batches, which can then tolerate a higher learning rate. Larger batches reduce regularization, larger learning rates add it back. But that will not be a perfect match to compensate, so you will still want to adjust accordingly.

In general, whenever you change your batch size you will also want to re-tune your learning rate to compensate.

---

*Leslie N. Smith* has written some excellent papers on a methodical approach to hyperparameter tuning. A great place to start is [A disciplined approach to neural network hyper-parameters: Part 1 -- learning rate, batch size, momentum, and weight decay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09820). He recommends you start by reading the diagrams, which are very well done.

Comment: all my research on the matter led me to regularization topics. and your answer also suggest it, if you can elaborate a little bit more about the first point where the learning rate will be high for the now-accumulated gradient that would be very helpful.

Comment: @YehdhihANNA I'm glad this was on the right track. I have updated my answer with additional detail on the gradient accumulation. Let me know if you need any additional clarification!

Comment: thank you very much for the extrq details.
btw can u put a link to a  tutorial for re-tuning the learning rate (isnt the adam optimizer doing that by default?)

Comment: This is actually a common misconception. Adam will help different parts of the network to adjust and train in sync, but it is still essential to tune the overall learning rate. I have updated my answer with my favorite paper on the subject.

Comment: These articles would be a great help: [Exploring Learning Rates to improve model performance in Keras](https://towardsdatascience.com/exploring-learning-rates-to-improve-model-performance-in-keras-e37f5e63f16c) || [Learning Rate Schedules and Adaptive Learning Rate Methods for Deep Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-rate-schedules-and-adaptive-learning-rate-methods-for-deep-learning-2c8f433990d1).

Comment: @mcskinner thanks man you were a big help I appreciate it. you too @'Muhammad Usman'